# Is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS safe enough to try it now for professional use?

Tags: upgrade, lts, 18.04

I am planning to migrate from **Ubuntu 16.04** to **Ubuntu 18.04** with a *fresh install*..
Has anyone tried the **final stable release** of Ubuntu 18.04?
and
Did anyone encounter any **errors/issues** while installing it?
*In other words*, ***is it safe enough to try it now, or shall I give it more time before I install it?***

**Update:**
This is not about "new release missing or not found", it is about user experience while trying the new release.

Comment: Status of tests and bugs can be found at http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/389/builds.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has not been released yet. Therefore there is no "final stable release" yet. The obvious answer to your question, then, is to wait, but I'm not writing this an answer because it'll obviously be out of date in a few hours.

Comment: LTS is out on the Canonical Website www.ubuntu.com. At the same time I'm seeing lots of Ubuntu 18 questions blowing up on this forum. I also think this question deserves to be revived as an independent question as the other ones don't specify Ubuntu 18 and do not definitively address whether it is safe for professional (casual) users.

Comment: This answer satisfies my curiosity https://askubuntu.com/a/1029998/279440

Comment: What is wrong with people conflating these sorts of questions (is it a good idea to upgrade yet/is it stable/etc) with "why do i get an error when trying to upgrade"? That's like me asking "Are oranges in season yet?" and having it flagged as a duplicate of "Why does this green orange taste bitter?". Related? Yes. Duplicate? No.