# Is it a bad idea to upgrade to 18.04 right now?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 18.04

I started using Ubuntu about 2 years ago and at that time installed 16.04 LTS. A few days ago 18.04 LTS launched. Is it necessary to upgrade to this new version right away, since LTS distro's are supported for 5 years?

Comment: Read the top upvoted bounty awarded answer.

Comment: No, please upgrade right now! I'm waiting a few months and I rely on brave pioneers to hit all the problems I'd have hit had I not been patient!

Comment: The duplicate candidate title doesn't look the same to me... That should be part of the litmus test I think.

Comment: This isn't at all a duplicate of that question and should be unmarked as such. The "previous" question is asking why the user is receiving a particular error, not whether it's a good idea to upgrade.

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate, more like "Too Broad" and open to very opinionated/preferential answers. It's not a bad idea to upgrade to the 18.04 LTS at this point, you should do some research though and understand the impact of upgrading. "Will anything cease to function as expected when upgrading?" "Are there compatibility issues with applications I use on a regular basis?" are some basic questions you should ask yourself when choosing to upgrade.

Comment: pls upgrade 18.04 - I was using Ubuntu 16.04 But Many programs crashed . like `OpenShot` , `Gimp` and etc.My last problem with `Ubuntu 16.04‍‍‍` was this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180554/in-ubuntu-16-04-wired-connection-losing-the-internet-after-a-while-and-need-to-r/1181803#1181803

Answer (score 42):

In my opinion, it's not worth it.

I had been using Ubuntu 16.04.1 for 2 years. Apart from a few minor bugs, I had no problem with it. As soon as the new Ubuntu 18.04 was released (26 April), I did a clean installation.

But then came the major bugs.

1. Eclipse would refuse to start and give a missing runtime error, even though I installed it the exact same way I did it 2 years ago. After fixing that problem, Eclipse works, but it hangs alot.
2. Visual Studio Code refused to start, even though I installed it using command line (`sudo apt-get`), the exact same way I did few months ago. I had to manually make changes in the installation folders to fix it.
3. `sudo apt-get upgrade` gives Error 404 too often.
4. Ubuntu 18.04 lagged a lot, even though Ubuntu 16.04.1 ran smoothly.
5. Ubuntu 18.04 hangs an average thrice a day and doesn't recover from it, so I have to do a force shutdown. Unlike Ubuntu 16.04.1 which would usually recover on its own.
6. Sometimes Ubuntu 18.04 hangs at the login screen itself. Again, force shutdown is the only solution.
7. Most problems reported on Ask Ubuntu, Stack Overflow and YouTube are for older versions. And their solutions don't work for Ubuntu 18.04.
8. SciDAVis, a plotting software for scientific data, is not available in Ubuntu 18.04 anymore due to dependency issues.

It took me an entire Sunday to get all my software running again. And I haven't solved all the problems yet.

So, if you really want to upgrade, wait for Ubuntu 18.04.1 which will come out soon. The current version has been released in a hurry to meet the deadline. If you don't need anything from the new upgrade, then it's a risk you're taking.

Good luck ;) if you're willing to risk it.

Comment: Thank you for your very useful answer. Since everything is up and running, I am not willing to take the risk!

Comment: When I upgraded 16.04 to 18.04 in test environment it installed 5 different Desktop environments you can pick from gear next to "Sign In" button. Which interface / DE were you using?

Comment: I completely have the same problems, on two different laptops. One is a Lenovo which I use with X.org and my home laptop which is an Asus, and that I use with Wayland. These laptops ran 16.04 and 17.10 pretty smoothly. 18.04 seems to me the worse release in the last 3 years.

Answer (score 14):

### Not necessary at all to upgrade now, but you are welcome to do it

You are welcome to upgrade to 18.04 LTS, but several bugs will be found (and squashed) during the first months. If you want to join the adventure to test the latest and greatest, yes you can try to upgrade, but first you should ['Try Ubuntu' live](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389) from the installation media, and then make a test installation alongside your production operating system or [installed in an external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312).

You should always **backup everything important** before you start upgrading to a new version.

### Wait for 18.04.1 LTS, if you want a smooth ride

If you want a smooth ride, you should wait until the first point release in July or August. By that time this new version, 18.04.1 LTS will be polished and debugged. Also the procedure for upgrading will be much more reliable than now.

Comment: lol now that 18.04.1 LTS is out .. OMG its horrible and I don't know what I'm going to do when I have to update my server because everything is broken on it and they  removed everything that users use ..like the biggest GKSU so you cant run any program as root and lol .. don't try to set something to start at boot in the startup settings app like you used to... it doesn't save your entries .. guess you have to be root to save the entries made .. but .. you cant launch it as root .. if you arent a command line guru.. get ready to learn linux all over again

Comment: @JohnOrion So in short don't upgrade to 18.04?

Comment: @FrankGroot  It's a big learning curve, It breaks a lot of stuff I use and takes away a lot of things like gksu, a gui for an app and it seems they got rid of sqlite which is a common database that many programs I have installed use so I don't know how programs like fail2ban are going to work .. this is why I will not  update my server with it, The gksu can be worked around but its no longer as simple as adding a command to the launch line. I guess the other issues can be "worked around too" but as I say, it's a whole new learning curve so if you arent a guru with Linux its going to be tough

Comment: I will say after some time with it. some of the things I was able to get working but the server has been running 24/7 for over 9 years and has gone through a lot of modifications and updates to the OS. I think when it went from 14.04 to 16.04 I also had updating breakage that needed fixing to keep the system running without losing the modifications already done. Its been so long and so many mods that I don't even remember them all. I'm not good with linux(I google a lot). Since the server I have is many things-web,email,ftp, DVR, NAS, Personal Cloud, 3 cam security system and a radio station.

Comment: lol I ran out of space .. but with all that said .. my system is quite "busy" I am running it now on a computer I have in my kitchen which is just a basic internet browser video streamer for when I'm doing dishes or cooking lol .. and its fine on that system so... It depends on what your system is set up for and how "in depth" or necessary for everything to be functioning perfectly in a very short time .. its not Horrible as I first stated ... just not an easy upgrade for a "packed" system but it seems fine for a basic system

Comment: @JohnOrion, I agree with your statement: [Upgrading to 18.04.1 LTS is] "not Horrible as I first stated ... just not an easy upgrade for a "packed" system but it seems fine for a basic system".

Answer (score 3):

If you have enough disk space to hold an extra copy of **Ubuntu 16.04** then I'd say it's worth upgrading to **18.04** on a **cloned test version** today, tomorrow, next week and next month.

Each time you upgrade you will learn a little bit more about new features, new bugs and new fixes to bugs you encountered the last time. By the time you are ready to upgrade for real you'll be confident the process will be error free and have a good understanding of how to use the new applications and OS.

You can boot with a Live USB and manually clone your Ubuntu 16.04 partition or you can run this script: [Bash script to clone Ubuntu to new partition for testing 18.04 LTS upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-clone-ubuntu-to-new-partition-for-testing-18-04-lts-upgrade).

You can also create a **test plan** for what you need to test after upgrading your cloned 16.04 to 18.04: [Is 18.04 already somewhat safe for installing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010954/is-18-04-already-somewhat-safe-for-installing/1011153#1011153)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it necessary to upgrade to this new version right away, since LTS distro's are supported for 5 years?

It is not "necessary"[1] and you're not "required"[2] to upgrade if you don't want to. Generally, it's *recommended* that you do so, but it doesn't need to be "right away", as in immediately.

You can wait for the first point release of 18.04.1, which comes out roughly one month from initial release. At that time, the system will show a message that a new release is available, in which case, the command `sudo do-release-upgrade` will find and apply the update.

However, if you choose to upgrade before then, you can do so with the `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` (notice the extra `-d` argument).

You should take a look at the documentation, as it lists the known issues and other things you should probably be aware of *before* you choose to upgrade.

---

[1] By "necessary", I mean in the sense that your system won't stop working if you choose not to upgrade.

[2] By "required", I mean you're not obligated/forced to do so.

Answer (score 2):

My latest post was deleted apparently.

So I'll answer again (yes again, to warn the topic starter that what he wants to do might indeed be bad idea right now... having found out by actually performing the upgrade.):

so here it goes: Yes it would be a bad idea.

why?
because i just tried upgrading 16.04 to 18.04 today and it froze up.

the 16.04 install was completely up to date and didn't have any custom packages installed so fairly clean to begin with.

Comment: for who cares: apparently this issue can happen if you don't disable automatic lockscreen according to another askubuntu user.

Answer (score 1):

Well, define *necessary*. This decision is totally up to you and I would say it depends on your needs. If by *necessary* you mean that you need to upgrade to 18.04 so that you can do something that at the moment you can't do, then I guess you would know the answer yourself. Otherwise if you're happy with 16.04 and you don't see the need to upgrade to 18.04 then don't, your system will run the same way it's doing now.

I don't think this community can make this decision for you.

I personally like running the latest LTS on my work laptop and the latest version (LTS or not) on my personal laptop, but that's just my personal decision.

Comment: Necessary to me means that I wouldn't be able to use a certain program that I am using now.