# In Ubuntu 16.04 wired connection losing the Internet after a while and need to reconnect

Tags: 16.04, networking, network-manager, internet, wired

I'm using **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** and everything is upgraded and updated in my system .

But when i'm using internet with **wired connection** i will lose internet once in a while !

For using internet i must go `setting/network` and **wired connection** need to turn off and turn on again to work .

[image]

And this is my network driver information after running `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 19
   bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
   logical name: eno1
   version: 04
   serial: 70:f3:95:01:c4:63
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.4.2.4-NAPI duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 ip=192.168.1.156 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:28 memory:f7c00000-f7c1ffff memory:f7c39000-f7c39fff ioport:f080(size=32)
```

I checked my Lan cable . i tried updating my network driver and ... but i could't solve this problem .

how can i solve this problem ?

*UPDATE 1 : 
setting of wired connection : 
[image]

Comment: You probably have a cabling problem, as you're only getting 100Mb speed, or a switch/hub/router/modem that doesn't support 1Gb speed. Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 ethernet cabling? Please describe your ethernet cabling from the computer port to the modem.

Comment: @heynnema i have 2 safe lan cable and i changed the cable but problem not solved  . i'm using cat5e cable . my modem is a LTE 4G modem

Comment: Check the specs on your 4G and see if it supports 1G speeds. It probably doesn't. That would explain the 100Mb speed that you're getting. The problem is probably an unreliable connection on/via the 4G modem. Does the modem show signal strength?

Comment: ps: some 4G modems have a setting which puts the modem to sleep, or disconnects after a set period of inactivity. Check your modem's settings panel.

Comment: @heynnema problem is not about modem because when my ubunutu is disconnected i can use internet by wifi on another device

Comment: and i have not this problem in windows os . it's ubuntu problem or wrong setting i dont know

Comment: You didn't answer/check either of my questions. Signal strength indicator, and "bandwidth saver" or "idle timeout" values settings? Please describe all of your cabling from the computer port to the modem. Is there a router? You mention that it works on another device via wifi... does it work from Ubuntu via wifi? Don't dismiss the idea that the problem may have to do with the 4G connection. The fact that it works on Windows has no relationship as to the problem when using Ubuntu.

Comment: @heynnema There is no router . I plugged the cable directly into the computer from the modem Without anything in the middle . when my ubuntu does not have internet access I can use the same modem by Using its WiFi . i can not connect to wifi by my ubuntu because my computer have not any wifi hardware . and finally My modem has no signal problems . i think it's ubuntu bug or configuration problem or driver problem ...

Comment: The next easy thing to try is to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if the problem still exists. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema i boot Ubuntu 16.04 from USB and the problem still exists

Comment: What is your computer make and model #? Do you have any other ethernet connection that you can try... work... school?

Comment: @heynnema i'm using `Lenovo mini case model : m92p` , No i have Not any other ethernet connection .

Comment: @abasnikzad post a screenshot of your wired connection settings using nm-connection-editor

Comment: @kannzzmm2 updated by wired connection settings

Comment: @abasnikzad sudo apt-get install ethtool and then run sudo ethtool -s eno1 autoneg  off

Comment: @kannzzmm2 `Cannot set new settings: Invalid argument
  not setting autoneg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

Problem still exists when booting from a Ubuntu 16.04 Live USB. **Try booting to a Ubuntu 19.04 Live USB and see if the problem is solved.**

Check your BIOS version...

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
```

It should be version 9SKT9CA.

If not, go to https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds029265 and download one of the updaters and apply.

**Update #1:**

User reports BIOS is 9SKT9CAUS

**Update #2:**

User reports that the problem is solved when booted to a Ubuntu Live 18.04 USB, but wishes to stay with 16.04.

**Update #3:**

User decided to upgrade to 18.04 anyway, and the problem is solved.

Comment: the version of bios is `9SKT9CAUS` . Do I need to update?

Comment: @abasnikzad I suspect that 9SKT9CAUS is probably fine. Do try the Ubuntu Live 19.04 or 19.10 (available on 10/17/19) and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: I tested on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS latest version and problem solved but i prefer to use 16.04 .

Comment: @abasnikzad as you might expect... I'd encourage you to upgrade to 18.04 or newer.

Comment: So we conclude that the problem is `Ubuntu 16.04`

Comment: @abasnikzad I would say yes.

Answer (score 0):

With Mr. @heynnema 's guidance and answer we conclude that the problem is `Ubuntu 16.04` .

I checked problem in `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` [ubuntu live from USB] and the problem was still there .

Now i upgraded to `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` and my problem is solved .